# I want to disable google payments when registering credit card

Tags: javascript, google-pay

I'm developing a web page to handle credit card information from user.
It's a form.

After processing, automatically, Chrome pop up and save credit card information, it seems called Google payments.

At this time, as we tokenized credit card, we don't need raw credit card number etc... So this Chrome's behavior might make customer confused...

Can I disable that Chrome save it?

[image]

Comment: If possible, try changing input `name` and `type` in html, it may work. And let me know, it works or not.

Comment: @mahfuz thanks! however sorry.... I decide to make input values empty before redirecting...

Comment: welcome. at least you have found a solution.